# Mysql INT with a character

Tags: mysql, int, varchar

I have a mysql database with a field "order_number" set as an INT on the odd occasion the order number would need to have a trailing r eg 2100r obviously INT will only accept numbers and would sort the number correctly ASC or DESC if I use VARCHAR to overcome this restriction it will correctly accept the trailing r character but will not sort the numbers in numerical order correctly, is there a way INT option can be forced to accept a character?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your account ids as character strings if any of them contain letters.  But you can order them correctly as long as the letters are always suffixes. This works whether or not your AccountID values have leading spaces.

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Account
 ORDER BY CAST(AccountID as UNSIGNED INTEGER), AccountID
```

This will order numerically, and then deal with any equal numbers by ordering lexically.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a16bf/8/0

If you wanted the "r" orders to be shown before their unadorned friends with the same number, you could do this:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Account
 ORDER BY CAST(AccountID as UNSIGNED INTEGER), AccountID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CAST` function in MySQL but it's a good practice to store `order_number` as int using typecasting before inserting new data in table.

```
SELECT CAST(int_col AS CHAR);

SELECT CAST(char_col AS unsigned INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option.

You should probably use a `VARCHAR` column for the order number and a separate column (possibly `INT`) just for sorting; populate the helper column based on what the order number is when inserting and updating rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert string to number using this way (number_string * 1), e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column * 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

No , Not possible. As @Jon said, there is no other options to force an `INT` field to keep `VARCHAR` data.